# Sequence difference inequaity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

If $\{a_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an increasing  sequence of real numbers such that $|a_{n}-a_{m}|\geq \alpha>0$ for all $n\neq m$. Can we assume something like
$$|a_{n}-a_{m}|\geq nm \quad   \quad..........(*)$$
for large $n,m$?

If this is not true, can we find another lower bound depending on $m$ and/or $n$?

Comment: $a_{m+r}-a_m=(a_{m+r}-a_{m+r-1})+(a_{m+r-1}-a_{m+r-2})+\cdots+(a_{m+1}-a_m)\ge r\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

No, what about the series where there is a recursively defined series $a_{n+1} = a_n+\alpha$ for small $\alpha$. We can’t find a bound on the term you are looking to bound because the elements of the sequence doesn’t have to have any dependence on the index of the element other than that it is at least $\alpha$ bigger than the previous element in the sequence.

Comment: Okay. Do you think there are such sequences with property (*) above?

Comment: Absolutely, an example would be $a_{n+1} = 2^{a_n}$

Comment: What about a class/ a characterization of sequences with property (*)?

Comment: To my knowledge the way you would classify this set of sequences would be using the bound you gave above. Counterintuitive? Maybe, but that is all you can do in this case